# Update statement in nested query

Tags: mysql

I have an update query.But it showing sql error

**Query**

```
Update ms_student set student_first_name=y.student_first_name,student_middle_name=y.student_middle_name,student_last_name=y.student_last_name FROM
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as student_first_name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as student_middle_name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) as student_last_name
FROM   ms_student) y
```

My inner query working perfectly.But In update having issue

Comment: Any clue as to what error it is showing you?

Comment: can you give a mysql error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need subquery you can do with simple update command

```
update ms_student
set 
student_first_name= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),
student_middle_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),
student_last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) ;
```

Comment: thank u sir.Its right.But one thing the student_name contain only first name and middle name no last name.Here shows the middle name as last name

Comment: Please provide some sample data of your student_name

Comment: the student_name is Aahil Niyas.The first name is Aahil,middle is Niyas third name is Niyas.if the student_name contain 3 names its working okey

Comment: No.The names are mixed.Some names are 2.others are 3.

Answer (score 0):

You came have multiple table in update clause

```
Update ms_student x,(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as student_first_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as student_middle_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) as student_last_name
    FROM   ms_student) y
    set x.student_first_name=y.student_first_name,x.student_middle_name=y.student_middle_name,x.student_last_name=y.student_last_name;
```